# Automatically download files in FTP server

Tags: c#, ftp, ftp-client

I don't have any knowledge about C# but I need to create an FTP server that automatically download a list of files (one by one, from the last to the first), so I downloaded some source codes of FTP servers and the most functional I found have a little problem, my task is to get a server that download files automatically, but the code I get open an window to select where to save the file.

How can i change it to download the files automatically?

(If possible, explain throughly how your code work, it will help me to better understand and learn C#)

```
private void ServerFileListView_DockChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in ServerFileListView.Items)
    {
      item.Selected = true;
    }

    byte[] file;

    Server.Download(MachineInfo.GetJustIP(), ServerFileListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text, out file);

    SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
    save.Title = "It saves the downloaded file.";
    save.SupportMultiDottedExtensions = false;
    save.Filter = "*.png|*.png";
    save.FileName = ServerFileListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text;
    if (save.ShowDialog() != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(save.FileName, file);
        MessageBox.Show(ServerFileListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text +" has been downloaded.", "FTP File Sharing", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    save.Dispose();
}
```

If you want more details ask in the comments.

*(Sorry for bad speech, i'm not fluently in english)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the SaveFileDialog() it is meant to save file interactively.

- Get the list of the file and put in array
- and loop (foreach) the array to run the download method
- better yet, run the method in a separate thread or async, so it will not block the main thread.

Pseudo:

```
{run in thread

    if(ftp is connected)
    {
       connect;
       string listToDownload[] = getListFileFromServer;
        foreach (var item from listToDownload)
         {file = getFileFromServer;
          saveToDisk(file);
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! With some edits it solved my problem! \(^-^)/